# Come support the Yiddish.SE proposal!

Tags: discussion

The Yiddish forum proposal is having what could properly be called a "rally" (by the standards of the Yiddish-speaking, Internet-accessing world...).

It would be great to have such a forum open.

Please support it by asking some sample questions and/or voting on the ones that are there.  Contributions can, apparently, be in English!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79092/yiddish?referrer=mqSPG9PtJlDGHtHjFYFfOw2

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2212/759

Comment: I definitely saw the other question before posting this one. The goals of our questions are totally different. It's not a duplicate.